# angularjs - Protractor - run test on different port numbers

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

We have a client application built on angularjs. We are using protractor for e2e testing. Our code base is visual studio online with continuous integration implemented. Whenever there is a check-in and a pull request (PR) created, the build is triggered which includes multiple steps. One of them is running e2e test cases.

We have a single build machine which takes care of individual developer's PR builds and also the prod builds once these PRs are merged with the master.

**Problem** - On the build server, if there are two or more simultaneous builds running, only one of them succeeds and the rest of them fail because of e2e failure. The problem here is, e2e's try to run on the same port every time, and if it is occupied, then there is a failure in execution of this step.

I am sure this might be a problem for many and might have been solved.
Looking for suggestions and probable solutions.

Is there a way to run each of them on different port number ?

Below is the protractor config

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                '--start-maximized'
            ]
        }
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:443/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000,
        print: function () { }
    },
    beforeLaunch: function () {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e'
        });
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
        var failFast = require('jasmine-fail-fast');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you want your client application run on different port number? or want selenium server start on different port number?

Comment: @yong we are looking if we the build for each pull request can run the E2Es without failure. So in that case, i guess it might be a different port for each instance of selenium server.

Comment: Could you give your protractor conf file and package.json file?

Comment: @yong As requested, have shared the protractor config file

Comment: You had set `directConnect` to true,  with such setting, protractor will start a chromdriver instance on a random and unused port of the machine where your script inside.  Thus with `directConnect =  true`,  Protractor will make webdriver run on different port automatically.

Comment: I noticed you set `baseUrl: 'http://localhost:443/'`, is this the home url of you app under test?  Do you want the app run on different port, not all start at `443`?

Comment: running on different port other than 443 would be great

Comment: You need to find out a way to get a free port dynamically , then start web application on the free port.  And the solution should also make test script can know the choosed free port, thus your protractor conf file can use the dynamical port in `baseUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

For protractor conf file:

1) If DirectConnet to true, e2e script running no need use selenium server, so no port number issue

2) If DirectConnet false/not set and seleniumAddress set to local/remote selenuim server address like: `http://xxxxxxx:4444/wd/hub`
one port number can support mulitple build running, but all build's e2e running will send webdriver commands to one selenium server, this will make all e2e running become slow and increase failure rate.

you can start new selenium server for per build to avoid it. To archive this, you can remove DirectConnet and seleniumAddress lines in conf file, protractor will start a selenium server on different port automatically when not set DirectConnet and seleniumAddress in conf file.

If you want to control port number, you can write a scrip to calcaute all available ports of script machine, then choose one to start selenium server.

3) If DirectConnet false/not set and seleniumAddress set to a selenium grid, you no need to worry port number issue.

Comment: have tried the above options, but didn't find it helping.